# owl-carousel plugin is not working with angularjs2

Tags: jquery, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using a jquery theme in my ASP.NET MVC core Application (angularjs2).
Some sections are properly working but some of the plugins are not working.

Like own-carousel is not getting the images and displaying anything.

I have placed the images folder under angular app folder as well under root project directory but it couldn't work in any case.

i am placing some code sample here:

please see and suggest.

index.component.html

```
<div id="hero">
      <div id="owl-main" class="owl-carousel owl-inner-nav owl-ui-sm">
    <div class="item" style="background-image:  url('app/assets/images/sliders/slider01.jpg');">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="caption vertical-center text-left">
          <div class="big-text fadeInDown-1">
            Save up to a<span class="big"><span class="sign">$</span>400</span>
          </div>
          <div class="excerpt fadeInDown-2">
            on selected laptops<br> & desktop pcs or<br> smartphones
          </div>
          <div class="small fadeInDown-2">
            terms and conditions apply
          </div>
          <div class="button-holder fadeInDown-3">
            <a href="single-product.html" class="big le-button ">shop now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.caption -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.item -->
    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('../assets/images/sliders/slider01.jpg');">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="caption vertical-center text-left">
          <div class="big-text fadeInDown-1">
            Want a<span class="big"><span class="sign">$</span>200</span>Discount?
          </div>
          <div class="excerpt fadeInDown-2">
            on selected <br>desktop pcs<br>
          </div>
          <div class="small fadeInDown-2">
            terms and conditions apply
          </div>
          <div class="button-holder fadeInDown-3">
            <a href="single-product.html" class="big le-button ">shop now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.caption -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.item -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.owl-carousel -->
</div>
```

Images folder is currently available under app folder in assets folder.

and this is parent/master layout which have that plugins

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="app/app.component.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <link href="node_modules/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/assets/css/colors/green.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/assets/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/assets/css/owl.transitions.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/assets/css/animate.min.css">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Icons/Glyphs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/Cartjs/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="node_modules/Cartjs/assets/images/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDDZJO4F0d17RnFoi1F2qtw4wn6Wcaqxao&sensor=false&amp;language=en"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/gmap3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/css_browser_selector.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/echo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/jquery.easing-1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/jquery.customSelect.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

    <!-- End Customizable plugins For Sale Cart Portal  -->
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>  
</head>
<body>
    <pm-app>Loading App...</pm-app>
</body>
</html>
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: You have a ton of problems and some serious misconceptions here. Also none of this has anything to do with asp.net core

Comment: no the underlying structure is in asp.net mvc core for managing db operations and others by ASP.NEt MVC Controllers.

Comment: guide if i am going in wrong direction. cant i use a theme based on jquery plugin with angular ? rest things are working fine except just this plugin

Comment: Client !== Server is what I mean. If you think there is a dependency between ASP.NET MVC and Angular 2. You are mistaken. If you do not think there is such a dependency, then your question is incorrectly framed.

Comment: Aluan , i am not saying this. i am just asking the solution of it. i am giving the path but system is not getting thats' why i am saying that may be there is some difference in accessing the images under angular app folder and from other's under root (through MVC views).

Comment: <div class="item" style="background-image: url('../assets/images/sliders/slider01.jpg');">

Comment: I understand what you mean now, please post `systemjs.config.js`

Comment: please see above now

Comment: Pleas use separate code block for correct syntax highlighting

Comment: Aluan, Do we need Code formation/identation ?

Comment: To read your question but I fixed it for you I just didn't have time to answer it after that